# How can I get arguments of callers and is there any way to marshal them

Tags: go

I'm trying to do some work like a traffic interception on function level, is there any way to know the caller arguments(runtime is better)? I've found runtime package provide a way to get caller information like file name and line number, but I'd like to know the true arguments value, and I'd like to marshal them, can I do this in GO?

Maybe this code can make it clear:

```
func parent(ctx context.Context, a int, b string, c int){
    '''do some work'''
    children(a, b)
}

func children(a int, b int){
    ctx:=getFirstParentArg()  //get ctx from caller func parent
    '''do some work'''
}
```

Comment: Create a `ctx context.Context` argument in `children`, and pass in the value from `parent`. There is no other magic solution.

Comment: @HymnsForDisco This work is fine for new code, but for some old codes, it's difficult to change all the functions

Comment: For old code, you need to edit it.  There's no other way.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible in any reasonable way.

Comment: The common approach to handling this with legacy code is to add a `childrenContext` function that takes the new argument, leaving the old one for backward compatibility. Then `children` will call `childrenContext(context.Background(), a, b)`. This allows new code to use context, and old code to work unmodified.

Comment: Trying to implement this kind of stack inspection, if even possible, is sure to create far more nasty consequences (both short and long term) compared to just refactoring the code properly.  It seems as though maybe it was an oversight to begin with that these context-needing functions don't take a context argument.

Comment: @Flimzy Maybe static AOP like AspectGo do the code mock, make a new function with a argument context is more reliable?

Comment: @HymnsForDisco This work is remedy, we're considering a way to do this work with minimal intrusion into old code, so static generate may work in this situation? change all the old function  with a new ctx in AST, and generate new code call the function with ctx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I get arguments of callers [...] can I do this in GO?

No. There is no portable, reliable stable way to do this.

And it is a bad idea anyway.

Comment: Or is there other way to do this job, may consider static generate with AST? replace the old function with a new function with argument ctx, and change the code call it with a argument ctx.

Comment: @Woodrow If your functions are reasonably well named and able to be uniquely identified by a tool like grep then perhaps all you need is a grep+replace, or gofmt. You should take a look at those solutions first before you start implementing something you may not really need.

Comment: this are many projects, so i'm afraid a simple replace is not work.

Comment: @Woodrow Well, gofix still exists and it might be adaptable to your needs without too much fuzz. It basically does what you thought about AST generation.

Comment: @Volker It's much more closer, however, I'm finding a way to make it more automatically do the replace job for all the functions.